# signtool.exe Error: SignerSign() failed (-2147220492/0x800403f4) when signing Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, code-signing, signing, signtool

I am currently trying to sign VBA macros in Excel and Word and Powershell scripts via the cmd.

For this purpose I use the Microsoft signtool.exe as part of the Windows 10 SDK:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

Signing Powershell scripts using the following command works fine:

**signtool.exe sign /f "testca.pfx" /fd SHA256 /p "123456" "test.ps1"**

For signing macros in Office documents, "Microsoft Office Subject Interface Packages for Digitally Signing VBA Projects" is also required:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56617

I downloaded the .exe and executed it.

Registering the .dll files using: **"regsvr32"** also worked. The paths to the .dll files are visible in the registry.

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) is also installed.

So theoretically I should be able to sign Excel macros now.
However, my server receives an error message with an error code, which I can't find anything about in Google.

Here is the complete output:

> The following certificates were considered:
>  
>   Issued to: TestCA
>       Issued by: TestCA
>       Expires: Wed Feb 03 08:53:09 2021
>       SHA1 hash: E19CE363C88CDBCE677FA170008D0AB0D98A02DC
>
> After EKU filter, one certs were left. After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
>   After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left. The following certificate was selected:
>       Issued to: TestCA
>       Issued by: TestCA
>       Expires: Wed Feb 03 08:53:09 2021
>       SHA1 hash: E19CE363C88CDBCE677FA170008D0AB0D98A02DC
>
> The following additional certificates will be attached: Done Adding
>   Additional Store SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
>   **Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed. (-2147220492/0x800403f4)**

I have now performed the installation as described above several times on different computers, all with admin rights and current updates:

- Private win10 computer: .ps1 and .xlsm signing is possible
- VM with win10 from work: .ps1 and .xlsm signing is possible
- Private VM with win 7: only .ps1 signing works
- Private VM with Win10: only .ps1 signing works
- TerminalServer with Windows Server 2012: only .ps1 signing works

What you can probably say is that `signtool.exe` works as such, because I can sign PowerShell scripts on all machines.
But signing macros does not always work. Probably has something to do with the interface packages?

I hope somebody has had the same problem before and can help. Because I'm going crazy with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took me a long time, but I'm up and running now. If anybody else has the same problem:

The "Microsoft Office Subject Interface Packages for Digitally Signing VBA Projects" .zip contained a readme.txt saying "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributal (x86)" must be installed. The link behind it downloaded the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributal (x86)", which is the latest version.

I have now tested all available versions of the last years and the only working one is the 2010 version. I don't know why the readme.txt refers to a different version, but the bug and the "solution" are definitely reproducible.

Anyway, use Visual C++ 2010 and everything is fine!